# C# HttpClient POST using form-data with a key

Tags: c#, postman

I am trying to POST to an API. In postman it works but in C# world I am getting errors.

In postman the BODY is set to "form-data" with a key of "message" and a value of "some content i want to post".

I normally just send JSON in the body and job done. I've not sent using "form-data" before...I know I need to add something to the Client like I do with the token in the header I guess?

The error I get is "Unsupported Media Type"

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-access-token", token);            

HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(_baseUrl, _model);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Capture Postman results with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and the compare to c# results.  The default headers in c# are different from postman and need to be modified in c#.

Comment: No need for wireshark.  In Postman locate the tabs just below the URL { Params, Authorization, Headers, ... }  Go all the way to the right and you will see a button labeled "Code".  When you click it it will give you a list of languages.  Click a language and it will give you code in that language to recreate the Postman request in your selected language.

Comment: Thanks - Will look at the Code tab - looks promising!